# Is seeing indirect images of moon on Ganesh Chaturthi considered inauspicious?

Tags: ganesha, festivals, superstitions, chandra

On Ganesh Chaturthi, it is believed seeing moon is inauspicious and is believed to bring curse to the person for an entire year.

Will this only matter for the moon in the sky on that day? Or will it count for seeing indirect images of moon like on a television, in a portrait, in a mirror etc?

Comment: It will matter even if the view is indirect. The SyanantalOpAkhyAna is the story of Krishna viewing the image of the moon in a pot of milk and facing the adverse consequences.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Do you mean the Syamantakopakyhyana?  What scripture mentions Krishna looking at the moon before the story of the Syamantaka gem?

Comment: @Bharat G - If it is accidental, nothing will happen. If Ganesa is merciful god, he will not harm you. Else, what is the purpose of worshipping  god who will frighten and trouble humans. Dont worry nothing will happen. God is far more merciful than these humans, who create these false stories and interpolate into scriptures. What happens to muslim, buddhist, jain, christian or even astronomers who view the moon today. Nothing will happen.

Comment: I agree with krishna if it is accidental nothing will happen just have a prayishchita bhava and pray to god for his blessings it will automatically lessen the adverse effects and if you can do ganpati atharvasheersha 21 times it will be even more beneficial

Comment: Well i didn't see it, just got that doubt. I heard one who sees the moon on this day will get bad name due to events that one is not even responsible of. We call it by the word `Apanindha` in our language. God never harms us anyway. It is just apanindha that we face even when we see the moon. The effect could be lessened on worshiping god..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The vrata katha of Ganesha chaturthi has the story. Not sure which purana has the story.

Comment: @SreeCharan First of all Ganesha Chaturthi has no basis in Hindu scripture; it only started being celebrated a few hundred years ago.  So any "Vrata Katha" associated with Ganesha Chaturthi must be extremely recent.